# Xamarin Forms Hot Reload is Not Functioning

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, hot-reload

I have searched multiple times about this issue and saw thousands of posts here but unfortunately I am still have trouble with the Xamarin Forms Hot Reload while using it on VS.

Any help please??

I have tried every solution but with no success and here are my selections as in the image attached. I have tried also both Changes only & Full Page options but nothing is working. Additionally, I have rebuild my solution many times and my emulator but nothing is functioning. Here are my Hot-reload options.

[image: 1]

Comment: First of all, update all of your nuget package project to the latest, then close your VS, then delete the 'bin' and 'obj' folders, rebuild and run your project, if it worked as normal.

Comment: Ok, I'll change the comment into answer, and you can mark it in order to help more people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, update all of your nuget package project to the latest, then close your VS, then delete the 'bin' and 'obj' folders, rebuild and run your project, if it worked as normal.